# Compatibility conditions for the wave equation with boundaries

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I'm going through the solution of the boundary problem of the wave equation with the parallelogram theorem, and it states that for the problem:

$u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=\phi(x,t),\quad a < x < b,\quad t>0$ 
$u(x,0) = f(x),\ u_t(x,0) = g(x),\quad a \leq x \leq b$
$u(a,t)=\alpha(t),\ u(b,t)=\beta(t),\quad t > 0$

the compatibility conditions are:

$\alpha(0)=f(a),\ \beta(0)=f(b)$
$\alpha'(0)=g(a),\ \beta'(0)=g(b)$

which are clear, and finally:

$\alpha''(0)=c^2 f''(a),\ \beta''(0)=c^2 f''(b)$

which are equivalent for demanding that on the boundaries, the solution will obey to the homogeneous equation. Why is that a demand?